# urllib.request.urlopen: ValueError: unknown url type

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

I have a long-standing issue with urllib.request. What I do:

```
wahlrecht = urllib.parse.quote("http://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/")
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Here's the full traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/d069049/Documents/BCCN/Predictor/Backend/wahlrecht_polling_firms.py", line 72, in get_tables
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(wahlrecht)
  File "/Users/d069049/anaconda/envs/bccn2017/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/d069049/anaconda/envs/bccn2017/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 511, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "/Users/d069049/anaconda/envs/bccn2017/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/Users/d069049/anaconda/envs/bccn2017/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 355, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/Users/d069049/anaconda/envs/bccn2017/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 384, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'http%3A//www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/'
```

Comment: Well, uh... why are you quoting the url before opening it? Of course that would make it invalid...

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing the : as if its args, you need to open the URL without quoting it.
Otherwise you try to open http%3A
the following line creates your problem

```
wahlrecht = urllib.parse.quote("http://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/")
```

If you change it to

```
wahlrecht = "http://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/"
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

`urllib.parse.quote()` has a default parameter *safe='/'*, which ["specifies additional ASCII characters that should not be quoted"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting). In your url

> "http://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/",

the "*:*" after "*http*" is quoted and replaced by "*%3A*", so it becomes

> "*http%3A//www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/*",

which causes the error. You can add "*:*" to the *safe* parameter to avoid it being quoted. For example, use `urllib.parse.quote("http://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/",safe=':/')`.