# PythonAnywhere Issues

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I am a new python user. I'm getting the following error when trying to run my code in PythonAnywhere, despite it working fine on my local PC.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zachfeatherstone/imputations.py", line 7, in <module>
    html = urlopen(url).read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>
```

It's similar to: [urllib.request.urlopen: ValueError: unknown url type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258205/urllib-request-urlopen-valueerror-unknown-url-type).

**CODE**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os.path

url = input("Enter the URL you want to analyse:  ")
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
wordList = text.split()
 
#imputations
imputations = []

if "unprofessional" in wordList:
    unprofessional_imputation = "That our Client is unprofessional."
    imputations.append(unprofessional_imputation)
  
print(imputations)
#print(wordList)
#print(text)

#saving file
save_path = 'C:/Users/team/downloads'
name_of_file = input("What do you want to save the file as?   ")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")         
f = open(completeName, "w")

# traverse paragraphs from soup
for words in imputations:
   f.write(words)
   f.write("\n")
```

**My apologies if this has been answered before.** How do I manage to run this in PythonAnywhere so that I can deploy over the web?

Comment: `urlopen(url)` is denying your request. (What url are you using? See [mcve]) Doubt it has anything to do with where the code is running (although the server could deny all requests from PythonAnywhere, and there is not much you can do about that)

Comment: Any URL. For e.g. I just tried: https://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/, and it failed. Then I tried this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72792960/pythonanywhere-issues?noredirect=1#comment128574361_72792960) and it proceeded to the next step, asking me what I wanted to save the file as, then gave me the following error:

Comment: Enter the URL you want to analyse:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72792960/pythonanywhere-issues?noredirect=1#comment128574361_72792960
[]
What do you want to save the file as?   test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zachfeatherstone/imputations.py", line 76, in <module>
    f = open(completeName, "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/team/downloads/test.txt'

Comment: Your Downloads folder needed to be capitalized,I assume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It COULD be helpful to send header info along with your request. You can pass a [Request object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) into your request like this:

```
url = input("Enter the URL you want to analyse:  ")

header = {'User-Agent': 'Gandalf'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, header)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = html.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
```

Comment: Still having the same issue, sorry. I did find this:


`'url = input("Enter the URL you want to analyse:  ")
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")`


Which worked for some websites, but not others. Apparently this is a known issue with 403 / 503 errors due to Cloudflare and protection.

Comment: @blackcat I wouldn't call it an issue.. The people hosting those websites are responsiblly protecting their sites from being scraped or preventing DDOS

Comment: @OneCricketeer - well said, I misspoke when I said issue.